# rails - How to show an image as background in a style tag?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am currently developing a rails application. I am trying to show an image on background in html.erb file yet I cannot do this. I use following up code:

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: <%= asset_path('home-bg.jpg') %>">
```

What's the mistake I did? Can anyone explain this?

Thanks,
Bartu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put the `url` declaration in your `background-image` property. It should look like

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path('home-bg.jpg') %>)">
```

Otherwise, you're just including a raw url as the property.

Comment: You might want to wrap it in quotes: `style="background-image: url('<%= asset_path('home-bg.jpg') %>')"`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to wrap your background image in a url:

```
style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path('home-bg.jpg') %>)"
```

Links to background images must be wrapped in `url()`, otherwise your browser will not know where to go to get the image.